# Pine Script failed to plot some data

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to plot some data in pine script, some data failed to plot; here is the script

// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © subikshababu

```
//@version=5
indicator("Gain Loss Spread", shorttitle = "GLS")
Up=close>open
Down=close<open
int datapoints=input.int(defval = 3,title="total datapoints to check",minval = 1,maxval = 512)

meangain=Up? ta.sma((close[datapoints]+ta.change(close,datapoints)),datapoints):na
meanloss=Down?ta.sma((close[datapoints]-ta.change(close,datapoints)),datapoints):na

meanpopulation=ta.sma(close,datapoints)

gainlossspread=(meangain-meanloss)+close // to be plot

//RS=meangain/meanloss
//RSI=100-(100/1-RS)// to be plot

plot(meangain,color = color.green)
plot(meanloss,color = color.red)
plot(gainlossspread,color = color.blue,style = plot.style_circles) //not ploted?
plot(meanpopulation,color = color.aqua,linewidth = 2)
//plot(RSI) // not plotted
```

[the script plots this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qvAV.png)

Comment: What is not plotting?

Comment: i commented as not plotted--gainlossspread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`meangain` will only have a valid number if `Up` is `true`.
`meanloss` will only have a valid number if `Down` is `true`.

`Up` and `Down` are the opposites of each other so they cannot be `true` at the same time.

You calculate `gainlossspread` as `gainlossspread=(meangain-meanloss)+close`. Since either `meangain` or `meanloss` is `na` on a given bar, the result also becomes `na`. THat's why it is not plotting anything.

[image]

Comment: But the script is plotting mean gain and mean loss for every bar; i will add a snap shot of the indicator to my question; i'm confused

Comment: No, it does not. See my edit. I have also added a screenshot. You see a continuous line but that is because Tradingview connects two dots together. But in between, you have `na` values. Just move your mouse over the chart and observe the plot values.

Comment: Gratse, i changed plot style now only one is ploted

Comment: i used ta.valuewhen for gainlossspread calculation; i added close value as scaling

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did finally and after that i added rsi-that i will post as another answer

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at 
  https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © subikshababu

//@version=5
indicator("Gain Loss Spread", shorttitle = "GLS",overlay = true)
Up=close>open
Down=close<open
int datapoints=input.int(defval = 3,title="total datapoints to check",minval = 1,maxval = 512)

meangain=Up? ta.sma((close[datapoints]+ta.change(close,datapoints)),datapoints):na
meanloss=Down?ta.sma((close[datapoints]-ta.change(close,datapoints)),datapoints):na

meanpopulation=ta.sma(close,datapoints)
//bolinger band
meanstdev=ta.stdev(meanpopulation,datapoints,false)
hiband=meanpopulation+(meanstdev*3.619)
lowband=meanpopulation-(meanstdev*3.619)

gainlossspread=(ta.valuewhen(Up,meangain,1)-ta.valuewhen(Down,meanloss,1))+close // to be plot

plot(meangain,color = color.aqua,style = plot.style_circles,linewidth = 3)
plot(meanloss,color = color.fuchsia,style = plot.style_cross,linewidth = 3)
plot(gainlossspread,color = color.blue,linewidth = 2) //not ploted?
plot(meanpopulation,color = color.aqua)
plot(hiband,color = color.black)
plot(lowband,color = color.black)

//end
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**